# What is the fate of the Queen' original sound mixing console?

Tags: queen

I was on Queen's museum in Montreux where it was the recording studio of this famous rock group. There are many items preserved but the original large Neve console is replaced by the table with just pictures of the sound controls glued to the top of it. What you see in the photo is ... just paper.

Last Queen songs ever were recorded in this studio. Mercury was coming for an hour or two when he was already very seriously ill, and the rest of the band was waiting for him. Last tracks were recorded by him just following the drum, as the rest has not been written yet, he knew he will not await. Mixing in the later produced sound track was between the last tasks of this equipment. Looks like studio has been closed not long after, soon being converted into museum. There are still drums, synthesizer and large 24 track studio tape recorder still there, but the console is gone.

Why it has been removed and is a later fate of it?

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming it's a silly typo: Montreux, not Montreal... https://www.montreuxriviera.com/en/P978/queen-the-studio-experience

Comment: Anyway, this sounds like a question best directed to the museum - I'm sure they are happy to answer such questions.

Comment: This museum is relatively small and seems not having dedicated staff you envision.